# Django Ajax Form submit reloads after "success"

Tags: jquery, django, ajax, image, upload

extending from my previous post containing problems with django and ajax ([Django Ajax Image submit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60702993/django-ajax-image-submit)), I came, as mentioned in the EDIT, to the following situation:

My jquery/ajax call:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
      // This jquery changes the appearance of the django { form_image }
      var imgElement = $('#id_image');

      imgElement.css('visibility', 'hidden');

      console.log($('#id_image').attr('type'))

      // This function triggers the hidden submit,
      //  which triggers the ajax image request
      imgElement.on({
        change: function () {
          $('#hidden-submit-img').click();
        },
      });
    });


    // This jquery is for the ajax post of the image

    // Doing it with submit, the image wont get saved, but the request is "success"
    // $('#image_form').submit(function (event) {

    // Doing it with change, the image gets saved successfully, but the respond loads a new page
    $('#image_form').change(function (event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      $.ajax({
        data: {
          image: $('#id_image').val(),
          csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}'
        },
        enctype: $(this).attr('enctype'),
        type: $(this).attr('method'),
        url: $(this).attr('action'),
        success: function () {          
          console.log(1);

        },
        error: function () {
          console.log(0);
        }

      });
    });
    </script>
```

As described in the comments there is this strange behaviour, either the page wont get reloaded but the image doesnt get saved, or the image gets saved but the page renders to a white page only containing "success". I can see, that the `console.log(1)` actually executes, and THEN the white page gets loaded.

I tried to keep my files as simple as possible.

Here is my view in views.py:

```
def image_feedback(request): # url 'website:image-feedback'
    if request.method == 'POST':

        image = request.FILES.get('image')

        ImagesUpload.objects.create(
            image = image,
        )

        return HttpResponse('success')
```

models.py:

```
class ImagesUpload(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=renaming_file)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.image)
```

home.html:

```
<form id="image_form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="{% url 'website:image-feedback' %}">{% csrf_token %}
  <button class="btn btn-secondary" onclick="$('#id_image').click()">Import Image</button>

  {{ form_image.image }}

  <input id="hidden-submit-img" value="SUBMIT" type="submit" style="visibility:hidden">
</form>
```

I think I am close to the solution but maybe my skills are insufficient.

I want to upload an Image, store it in my database and keep my website going without reloading/refreshing.

Comment: Try returning a JsonResponse instead of a HttpResponse in your view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**your html form**

```
<form id="image_form"> #does not provide any attribute
{% csrf_token %}
{{ form_image.image }}
</form>
```

**jquery**
put jquery in same page where your form

```
<script>
 $("#id_image").change(function(){ // here my second change apply id of image field
        var formdata = new FormData(); //create formdata object


        formdata.append('image',this.files[0])
        formdata.append('csrfmiddlewaretoken',$('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val()); //apply csrf token
        $.ajax({
            url:"{% url 'website:image-feedback' %}",
            method:'POST',
            data:formdata,
            enctype: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            processData:false,
            contentType:false,
            success:function(data){
              //update src attribute of img tag
                $('#profile_pic').attr('src',data.url);
                $('#image_form').trigger('reset'); // This reloads the form for additional upload
            },
            error:function(error){
              //display error base on return the view
                 alert(error.error)
            }
        });
    return false;
 });
</script>
```

**your view**

```
def image_feedback(request): # url 'website:image-feedback'
    if request.method == 'POST':

        image = request.FILES.get('image')

        img = ImagesUpload.objects.create(
            image = image,
        )
        return JsonResponse(status=200,data={"url": img.url}) #return json response 
     else:
        return JsonResponse(status=203,data={"error": "unauthorized  request.!!"})
```

I give a lot stuff you see and apply in your code then open firefox browser see in network tab of inspect element return you status code see which status code return and let me know if any error

Comment: doing it like this I receive two errors, an `method='POST'` and `enctype='multipart/form-data'`is missing and `this.files is undefined` error. Adding the missing attributes won't solve the problem

Comment: I update my answer you need to change in script apply `$('#id_image').change` does this work check it

Comment: Now I get the `csrftoken missing or incorrect` exception, but it seems to get the file

Comment: I update answer, You need change in csrf token id in javascript form data here i give you see `$('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val()`

Comment: let me know what the error you got after appy the csrf id

Comment: So far, it is fine! I can upload and save the image and get a "success" respond from my ajax. BUT the problem still is I can do it only once. When I try to upload 2 images one after another, the second one doesn't work.

When I look at the python console, it seems to freeze at `"POST /feedback/HTTP/1.1" 200 15`, when I re-click my upload button it turn into a `"GET /project/home/?csrfmiddlewaretoken=pyk....." 200 8473` after the first image. The following file upload simply wont get recognized.

Comment: You need to handle validation Here after success of ajax request clear image input field in your success function of ajax `$(this).val('');` and handle at list one file select exception  other wise you upload your picture right so can you accept as right answer

Comment: I solved it! I didnt clear the image field value, but I reset the form in the success function as seen here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/reset. I think your field cleaning approach should do quite the same. THANK YOU very much!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209763/discussion-between-l-b-vasoya-and-pcmkr929).